# ReplaceAll in Javascript is returning the wrong number

Tags: javascript

Working on some javascript I inherited and can't figure this one out:

```
fa = parseFloat(replaceAll($("#face_amount").val(),',',''))
```

When `face_amount` is 999,999 (or any number with a single comma) `fa` = 999999 but when `face_amount` is 1,000,000 `fa` = 1000

`face_amount` needs the formatting commas for display purposes.

I'm very new to javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're going to need to see your `replaceAll` function.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I'm such a noob I didn't realize `replaceAll` was not a javascript function but instead a custom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `replaceAll` is doing, I can't really fix that line of code, but you could try using a different replace function instead.

```
fa = parseFloat($("#face_amount").val().replace(/,/g,'')) // This works, returns 1000000
```

I suspect the problem is that your `replaceAll` function isn't matching commas globally. The line of code below only finds the first comma, and stops there. Where the line of code finds all commas using a global regular expression.

```
fa = parseFloat($("#face_amount").val().replace(',','')) // This doesn't work, returns 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to eliminate any non-numeric or `.` values, you can use a simple regex before you `parseFloat`.:

```
var floater = parseFloat($("#face_amount").val().replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, ''))
```

Comment: You can use `\D` to match all non-digit characters instead of `[^\d]`

Comment: That's `parseInt()` that has a radix, `parseFloat()` doesn't have one.

Comment: @zer00ne derp! thank you very much, updated my answer.

Comment: @Adam good to know, thanks. AFAIK I still need to use `^\d` in this instance though so I can also include `\.` for floating point numbers

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but I included my `replaceAll` in the code:

```js
function replaceAll(str,from,to){
  var re = new RegExp(from,"g");
  return str.replace(re,to);
}


var face_amount = '999,999';
var fa = parseFloat(replaceAll(face_amount,',',''));
console.log(face_amount,': ',fa);

face_amount = '1,000,000';
fa = parseFloat(replaceAll(face_amount,',',''));
console.log(face_amount,': ',fa);
```